# Send Message to Slack Message to Slack Channel through Slack Chat.Post Message API?

Tags: python, api, slack, slack-api

Although this question has been asked . I am trying to send message to slack channel through slack chat.post message api [this link](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)
But the message is not being sent to channel and i am getting

```
successfully completed post_reports_to_slack and status code 200
```

the code is:

```
import requests
def post_image():
    url="https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage"
    data = {

        "token": "xoxb-7701412070-tooken",
        "channels": ['#channel_name'],
        "text":"Message to send", 
    }

    response = requests.post(
         url=url, data=data,
         headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})

    #response = requests.post(url=url, data=payload, params=data, files=file_upload)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("successfully completed post_reports_to_slack "
                      "and status code %s" % response.status_code)
    else:
        print("Failed to post report on slack channel "
                      "and status code %s" % response.status_code)


post_image()
```

I also tried to send file using post file api which is working fine.And using webhooks which is also working fine.But I want to send message through chat.post message API.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the Slack SDK. Slack has an SDK for Python [here](https://slack.dev/python-slack-sdk/). The first thing I noticed in your code is that the key `channels` should be `channel` and it should be a string. After some tests, it seems like Slack always returns 200 with possible errors. The final code should be:

```
import requests
def post_image():
    url="https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage"
    data = {

        "token": "xoxb-7701412070-tooken",
        "channel": 'C1234567890',
        "text": "Message to send", 
    }

    response = requests.post(
         url=url, data=data,
         headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})

    #response = requests.post(url=url, data=payload, params=data, files=file_upload)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("successfully completed post_reports_to_slack "
                      "and status code %s" % response.text)
    else:
        print("Failed to post report on slack channel "
                      "and status code %s" % response.status_code)


post_image()
```